# npm no me funciona "npm ERR! code ECONNRESET"

Tags: nodejs, npm

Estoy teniendo problemas con npm al instalar cualquier dependencia (o cualquier cosa en general),ya que me aparece el siguiente error:

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Favie\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-29T05_53_38_971Z-debug-0.log
```

Alguien tiene alguna idea sobre este error?. Busque en las configuraciones de red y no tengo ningun proxy instalado y lo intente con el firewall desactivado

Answer (score 0):

Me funcionó lo siguiente:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Luego intenta reinstalar de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba hacer la instalación en el caso de nextjs por cable de red.

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno -4077
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Aborting installation.
```